# GIT RM a file with a leading whitespace character in filename

Tags: git

I need help with a git issue.

I have managed to create a file with a space at the beginning of it's name. 
I also have the same file without the space. When I first created the file with the single space I added it and committed it to my local repo.

if I do a git rm it deletes the file I want to kepp not the file I want to get rid of..

How can I get rid of the version with the leading single space character in the file name..

Regards

Gus Denton 
Uni of New South Wales

Comment: Does quoting the filename work? `git rm -- " file"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Escape each space with a slash, for example:

```
$ la
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  3 stevek stevek 4096 2011-06-07 22:50 ./
drwxr-xr-x 40 stevek stevek 4096 2011-06-07 22:50 ../
drwxr-xr-x  8 stevek stevek 4096 2011-06-07 22:50 .git/
-rw-r--r--  1 stevek stevek    5 2011-06-07 22:50   test.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 stevek stevek    5 2011-06-07 22:50 test.txt

$ git rm \ \ test.txt
rm '  test.txt'

$ git commit -m'removed'
[master 8e629e2] removed
 1 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644   test.txt

$ la
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  3 stevek stevek 4096 2011-06-07 22:51 ./
drwxr-xr-x 40 stevek stevek 4096 2011-06-07 22:50 ../
drwxr-xr-x  8 stevek stevek 4096 2011-06-07 22:51 .git/
-rw-r--r--  1 stevek stevek    5 2011-06-07 22:50 test.txt
```

Comment: I love stackoverflow and thanks for your help.
I did the git rm \ partB2_1_insert.cfm and it did it.
git status shows that it is deleted so I imagine I should then do a commit is this last step correct (which is certainly implied by lost-theroy)

Comment: Yeah you are pretty right! Go ahead. Commit it. How about marking this thread with accepted flag?

Comment: I have clicked on the tick and it has gone green.. As a newbie here I assume that's how I accept the solution..
And thanks again to all